# How to have line labels on both sides of a Y-axis?

Tags: javascript, visualization, linechart, echarts

I would like to have line labels on both sides of a Y-axis, as in the following example:
[image]
I looked on ECharts examples and documentation, but I couldn't find which series type or options would allow me to do that...

Here are the data used in the example:

```
|------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------|
| Entity     | 1950.0 | 1960.0 | 1970.0 | 1980.0 |  1990 | Rank50 | Rank90 | Factor |
|------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------|
| Mitzerland |  30000 |  32000 |  40000 |  50000 | 60000 |      1 |      3 |      2 |
| Ataly      |  20000 |  40200 |  60500 |  72000 | 85000 |      2 |      1 |    4.3 |
| Bangolia   |  10000 |  20100 |  30500 |  42000 | 75000 |      3 |      2 |    7.5 |
|------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is inbuilt support for that. Best I can think of right now is to use the regular [endLabel](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.endLabel) for the end of the series and a [markPoint](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markPoint) with symbolSize 0 on top of the first datapoint as start label.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygiBTWBeGBtbBGAVgAYAaGAJgGZSLyAWM8vADjL0oLboHZGA2IgF0y2KjTwCy3cRy68YeOuLxCR7Tgp78alJYwCcymocGCA3AChQkWKjBQAllACeMLNgDkAWQRgA5iAANg4IHmTeTgBeqABOgb5wYR4AKiAxEA7AoeYWVuDQMGgxDqgQADIOBe45AGZpMAAU1gUOYHCoAB4wrfBIKOgAlDAA3hYwMM2wMSAA7m69yGhQ2K3tHTnjRSXllVAAdAAOAK4QABYNo-PjLgeoAFwwHsFgqGFjV2AIALb3MHaOLhWbU6wne40QyAe0xmJDBfzaZQQACNUIEHpcrptTrMHlAYkdULDMeM6jEvkgoLEHg0hhgAHyPOxwGDxFGBeYeGAAahg0Ow0L2gTsfigpxgAFoFII4QBfIlXckxADWAAUQK0oOi4ZtnF8kUEAMoOaIPUjalnI1Hog4gDKOcAPJ6oGpQDxy80QhAPbDDUBpODemh8oTCGAANwQgQJD3-TmcQLWghl0sxMveMoGljTFhAB3tYHmGKFfiZ6Pd4w6AEEOpUtZibr8PFlKQEYs43pjPd7vOAwo9kgS-x4AOqoRLhZKnI5DgBixSHBqQC6OYA8KZg5ZgzmrtZGcIbjojUde6flW1KD3PO2gFhlZiAA):

```js
const dataset = [[150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260], [230, 160, 70, 135, 147, 140, 110], [135, 147, 260, 340, 290, 110, 90]];
const entity = ['Mangolia', 'Mitzerland','Torsica'];

const seriesList = [];
for (const index in dataset) {
  const row = dataset[index];
  seriesList.push({
    type: 'line',
    name: entity[index],
    data: row,
    endLabel: {
      show: true,
      formatter: () => 'end label = ' + row[row.length - 1]
    },
    markPoint: {
      symbolSize: 0,
      label: {position: 'left'},
      data: [{coord: [0, row[0]], value: entity[index]}]
    }
  });
}

option = {
  legend: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: seriesList
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I have lots of rows, would it be possible to populate these labels automatically? I mean having iterators instead of ''end label', 150 and 'start label'.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly but you can create the markPoints when you initially create your series option. I adjusted the example to refelct multiple rows.

Comment: How could I also iterate on another array? For example on `var entity = ['Mangolia', 'Mitzerland','Torsica']` to add entities names.

Comment: You can use a `for (let index in array)` loop to loop over the indices and get the corresponding entity via index: `entity[index]`

Comment: Where shall I put this loop exactly?

Comment: I updated the example again. This will hopefully help.

Comment: Wonderful! Huge help, thank you again!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I have a last issue (I hope). I can't manage to make the legend appear (in order to select/unselect entities). `legend: {data: entity},` doesn't do anything...

Comment: if you read the [documentation of legend](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#legend.data) it says "If data is not specified, it will be auto collected from series. For most of series, it will be collected from series.name". So if you name your series they will automatically show up. I updated the example again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use endLabel to show label at end.

Also, to show label at start you can use Markpoint with formatter to show series name and start value.

[Example:](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygiBTWBeGBtbBGAVgAYAaGAJgGZSLyAWM8vADjL0oLboHZGA2IgF0y2KjTwCy3cRy68YeOuLxCR7Tgp78alJYwCcymocGCA3AChQkWKjBQAllACeMLNgDkAWQRgA5iAANg4IHmTeTgBeqABOgb5wYR4AKiAxEA7AoeYWVuDQMGgxDqgQADIOBe45AGZpMAAU1gUOYHCoAB4wrfBIKOgAlDAA3hYwMM2wMSAA7m69yGhQ2K3tHTnjRSXllVAAdAAOAK4QABYNo-PjLgeoAFwwHsFgqGFjV4jID9MzJO_jYAQAFt7nZHC4Vm1OsJ_jA7HAyggAEaoQIPS5XTanWYPKAxI6oP6Y8Z1GJApBQWIPDzDBAAX3mw2AdI8sLpRKu5JiAGsAAogVpQdGwzbOIFIoIAZQc0QepBFMHiKLRIwV4wOIAyjnA1MCqBqUDCMDVMFJ5KglJiDwaBwQMWBEAGGAAfDAAAYAEmGtvtQIgewAbghAgSGVgvT6HXtPgg9qA0nB8II6W6FeyFTGHtgmSAE1maD9sEJhDAgyH7nD7E5nJC1snBGz3nSBpY6bkQAdtWBGe8OgBBDqVYWYm4VjxZSkBGLON6YzM4bzgI0pAnLgDqqES4WSpyOy4AYsVl5KkMejmAPA3xunxs4B0PVSPnLdqWXV02OVtSg8vztoBY6TMIA)

**Start label**

```
markPoint: {
  symbolSize: 0,
  label: {
    position: 'left', 
    formatter: (params)=> `${params.value} = ${params.data.coord[1]}`
  },
  data: [{coord: [0, row[0]], value: entity[index]}]
}
```

**End label**

```
endLabel: {
  show: true,
  formatter: '{a} = {c}'
},
```

Comment: Thank you Abhay!  I have a question about your example. Imagine you'd have 145 instead of 135 for Torsica. How would you prevent the label overlap? I used `(labelLayout: {moveOverlap: 'shiftY'}` and `labelLine: {show: true}` to prevent overlapping on the right Y-axis.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19128

echarts has open issue for that.